# Install wildcard SLL on Apache2 2.2.22 for hundreds of sub-domains

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a site hosting a root domain and over 200 one level subdomains, e.g,. sub1.example.com, sub2.example.com etc. I want to install a wildcard SSL for the Apache 2.2.22 server on Debian 7 for this domain. Is there any easier way than editing each virtual hosts config file in /etc/apache2/sites-available?

Comment: Do you need to modify the existing `SSLCertificateFile` directives to this new wild card certificate, or are you adding SSL to your existing setup? Or if it's something else, please explain further.

Comment: This is a new SLL certificate; the site previously had no SSL certificate and sub-domains are accessed using HTTP on port 80. Each sub-domain has it's own config file in /etc/apache2/sites-available using <VirtualHost *:80>

Comment: So you have to create the configuration files anyway. Its the same directive in each file so should be easily scriptable. Alternatively, though I've not tried it myself, but `SSLCertificateFile` is valid in the server context as well as the virtual host context, so you can try setting it globally (i.e. outside of any `<VirtualHost>` block.